# How to exclude some cats from wp_list_categories using shortcut

Tags: shortcode

I would like to display categories of a custom post type but not all of them. I'm using shortcode like this **[categories exclude="56","59"]** but it doesn't work. Can we exclude some categories in shortcode?

```
    function theme_shortcode_categories( $atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'categoriespostcount'   => 'on',
        'categorieshierarchy'   => 'on',
    ), $atts ) );

    $h = $categorieshierarchy == 'on'? "1" : "0";
    $c = $categoriespostcount == 'on'? "1" : "0";

    $cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'post_type'   => 'theme_portfolio_image', 'taxonomy' => 'theme_portfolio_categories','show_count' => $c, 'operator' => 'NOT IN', 'hierarchical' => $h, 'echo' => 0);
    
    return wp_list_categories( $cat_args );
}

add_shortcode( 'categories', 'theme_shortcode_categories' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude needs to be in the $cat_args, and in the shortcode_atts. Like this:
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'exclude'               => '',
'categoriespostcount'   => 'on',
'categorieshierarchy'   => 'on',
), $atts ) );

```
$cat_args = array(
    'exclude' => $exclude,
    'taxonomy' => 'theme_portfolio_categories',
    'show_count' => $c,
    'hierarchical' => $h,
    'echo' => 0
);
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146071/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-page-how-to-exclude-some-cats-from-wp-list-categor); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.